# How to create a time based event in a MVC5 website?

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-mvc-5.2

What is the best design in order to have time based events? Like for example sending reminders to users let's say 60 days after their last login or so?

The system is currently built on MVC5 so I was thinking of adding some cronjobs at the ActionExecuted in the base controller that would trigger all the checks and stuff and do all the event based tasks.

Another approach I was thinking about was to actually create a desktop app (console app) and have it running all the time and get push notifications from the SQL server on new user registrations and then just keep the list and as soon as 60 days pass send the email, or query the server once a day to get the last login date for everyone and send the email if needed for any user.

I found this (http://www.quartz-scheduler.net) on another question on SO: 
[MVC - Run scheduled task even if nobody logs into app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361639/mvc-run-scheduled-task-even-if-nobody-logs-into-app)

And wanted to ask if that would be an even better option for the system?

An even better example would be that each month a newsletter should be sent to some users. How would that be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I ended up using Quartz.NET. I made the MVC application create the triggers and jobs and a separate server runs a console app that executes the triggers and jobs.

This can be achieved having Scheduler.Start(); in the console app and not having it in the web app.

Also the jobs and triggers are stored on an SQL server (Azure SQL) rather than RAM so both machines can access them.

I also had to ensure that the clocks were in sync to the second and change some variables in the `<quartz>` config part in Web.config and App.config:

```
 <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />
 <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true" />
```

Both systems should act in a cluster!